# O365: Outlook not able to set default signature for shared mailbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

We've been struggling for the pas few days in trying to find how to add a default signature to a shared mailbox.

The user has a personal mailbox and a shared mailbox which is added automatically when the person has full access rights.

However, we now try to add a signature for the shared mailbox specifically but we're unable to get the mailbox in the list with available e-mail accounts.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my experience, only the mailbox that configured mannually in your Outlook would be in the account list to set signature, and the auto-mapped shared mailbox would work with your primary maibox's signature.

In this case, if you need to set up a separate signaure for the shared mailbox, as a workaround, you could try to configure it in Outlook if it has a password.

If you don't like to configure it in Outlook, there may be other workarounds(such as add disclaimers on the server), for more information, please refer to this article:

[How to set up different email signatures for a shared mailbox and user mailbox in Office 365?](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/how-to-set-up-different-email-signatures-for-shared-mailbox-and-user-mailbox-in-office-365/)